# Cannot read property 'title' of undefined en PUG

Tags: nodejs, express, pug

Estoy intentando hacer un CRUD de preguntas simple utilizando Express y PUG.

El código parece compilar correctamente, hasta que quiero crear una pregunta nueva por medio de un formulario POST, el error que me muestra la consola es: `Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`

Mi código pug es:

```
form(method="post")
    div(class="form-group")
    label(for="title") Titulo de publicación
    input(
           type="text" 
           name="title" 
           id="title" 
           class="form-control" 
           placeholder="Escriba su titulo aquí" 
           required
          )    
          div(class="form-group")
            label(for="body") Publicación 
            textarea(
                     class="form-control" 
                     id="body" 
                     name="body" 
                     rows="3" 
                     placeholder="Escriba su prublicación aquí"  
                     required
                    )
                    div(class="form-group publicar")
                    input(
                          type="submit" 
                          value="PUBLICAR"  
                          class="btn btn-inline-secondary pregunta"
                         )
```

Y mi routes.js es:

```
module.exports = (app) => {
    let entries = [];
    app.locals.entries = entries;

    app.get('/comunidad',(req, res) => {
    res.render('comunidad', {
        title: 'Comunidad'
    });
    });
    app.get('/comunidad/nuevaPregunta',(req, res) => {
    res.render('nuevaPregunta', {
        title: 'Nueva Entrada'
    });
});

    app.post('/comunidad/nuevaPregunta', (req, res) => {
    if (!req.body.title || !req.body.body) {
        res.send(400).send('Entradas deben tener un título y un cuerpo');
    }

    let newEntry = {
        title: req.body.title,
        content: req.body.body,
        published: new Date()
}

    entries.push(newEntry);

    res.redirect('/comunidad');
    });
}
```

Entiendo que mi problema puede surgir dentro de mi view, pero realmente no logro encontrar donde está el error.

Answer (score 0):

Se soluciona agregando en mi app.js la linea de comandos:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```